# My outlook VBA code drops the odd email

Tags: vba, outlook

I put together some VBA code for Outlook 2007 which has been working predominantly fine.
Its basically designed to check incoming messages and store the subject, body etc into a database and the attachment into a folder. In general, it works fine, but out of 100 messages or so, it drops the odd email.

I previously had a problem where some emails were not being processed and stored in the database, but then discovered there was an issue with illegal characters, which i have solved now, so that cant be it. I've compared the emails being dropped to the one's that arent, in terms of message header, content to and from fields and i cant see **any** difference between the two emails at all, so am completely perplexed as to why they're being dropped. When i copy the content of the email and forward it back to the system again, the VBA code processes it fine.

I am pasting the code below (the code links to some modules which are used for checking illegal characters or concatenating strings)

```
Sub SaveIncomingEmails(Items As Outlook.MailItem) ' enable this to run macro inbound emails

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
   Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

' ================================================================
' Open a Connection using an ODBC DSN named "Delphi".
' ================================================================

cnn.Open "MyDB", "MyUsername", "MyPassword"


' ================================================================
' Constants declaration
' ================================================================
    Const olFolderInbox = 6
    Const olTxt = 0



' ================================================================
' variable declaration
' ================================================================

    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim SenderName As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim strSQLquery As String
    Dim strSQLquery1 As String
    Dim strSQLGTDResourceQuery As String
    Dim MessageHeader As String
    Dim strCommandQuery As String
    Dim strGTDIdQuery As String
    Dim AttachmentStr As String
    Dim strFailedRcp As String
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim hasattachment As String
    Dim AttachmentType As String
    Dim SenderAuthorised As String


    Dim strToEmail As String
    Dim strFromEmail As String

    Dim strBody As String
    Dim strSentDate As String
    Dim strReceivedDate As String
    Dim StrUniqueID As String
    Dim strCommandDate As String
    Dim strDomain As String
    Dim strBodyStripped As String

    Dim strSubjectStripped As String
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strGoalId As String
    Dim strFile As String

   Dim strSenderAccountDescription As String
   Dim strContentType As String
   Dim strMimeVersion As String
   Dim strReceived As String



' ================================================================
'   Intializing variables
' ================================================================

    i = 0

    Set objItem = Items

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set colMailItems = objFolder.Items
    Set Item = objItem

    strToEmail = Items.To
    strFromEmail = Items.SenderEmailAddress
    strSubject = Items.Subject
    strBody = Items.Body
    strSentDate = Items.SentOn
    strReceivedDate = Items.ReceivedTime

    'Initialize variables in a given format
    StrUniqueID = Format(Items.ReceivedTime, "ddmmyyyyhhnnss") & Items.SenderEmailAddress
    strCommandDate = Format(Items.ReceivedTime, "mm/dd/yyyy_hh:nn:ss")


    ' Grab the sender domain by stripping the last portion of the email address using the getdomain function
    strDomain = Module2.GetDomain(Items.SenderEmailAddress)

    ' Strip the body of illegal characters and replace with legal characters for insertion into SQL
    strBodyStripped = Module3.RemoveIllegalCharacters(Items.Body)
    strSubjectStripped = Module4.RemoveIllegalCharacters(Items.Subject)
    AttachmentStr = "images/no_attachment.png"

' ================================================================
' ================================================================
' ================================================================


' =====================================================
' Check list of authorised senders for xsCRM commands.
' Populate email addresses here
' =====================================================

If (InStr(strFromEmail, "AuthorisedSender1@email.com") > 0) Or (InStr(strFromEmail, "AuthorisedSender2@email.com") > 0) Or (InStr(strFromEmail, "AuthorisedSender3@email.com") > 0) Then

SenderAuthorised = "true"
End If



' ======================================================
' ======================================================
' ======================================================


' ================================================================
'  check if subject holds a command
' ================================================================
   'check to see if email sender is authorised
           If SenderAuthorised = "true" Then

    ' Check if the subject line contains the string xs4crm is true
   If InStr(strSubject, "xs4crm") > 0 Then


   'If its true then do this
   strCommandQuery = "INSERT INTO XSCRMEMAILCOMMAND (" & vbCrLf & _
           "FromEmail," & vbCrLf & _
           "command," & vbCrLf & _
           "date," & vbCrLf & _
           "Body" & vbCrLf & _
           ") VALUES ('" & strFromEmail & "','" & strSubject & "',GETDATE(),'" & strBody & "')"

           Set rs = cnn.Execute(strCommandQuery)




           'Look for a GTDID string so that we can save data to resources table
           If InStr(strSubject, "gtdid=") > 0 Then

          'Set the hasattachment variable to zero since we only want to run this loop if there are no attachments
          hasattachment = "0"

          'Set the variable to 1 so that we that our next if statement can only run if there are no attachments
          For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            hasattachment = "1"
          Next Atmt              


          If hasattachment = "0" Then

             'Grab the GTDId so we know which goal this resource belongs too.
             strGoalId = Module5.GetHeaderProperty(strSubject, "gtdid=", ";", 5)


            'Save data to table
             strGTDIdQuery = "INSERT INTO XSCRMGTDRESOURCES (" & vbCrLf & _
             "GoalId," & vbCrLf & _
             "insertdatetime" & vbCrLf & _
             ") VALUES ('" & strGoalId & "',GETDATE())"

             Set rs = cnn.Execute(strGTDIdQuery)

          End If

           End If
    End If
    End If


' ================================================================
' ================================================================
' ================================================================



' ================================================================
'  Create folders for atttachments
' ================================================================

    ' Save any attachments found
    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments

    AttachmentStr = "images/attachment.png"  'because it has gone into attachment loop the icon is now required.

    'Create the subfolder for the attachment if it doesnt exist based on sender domain

    Dim fso
    Dim fol As String
    fol = "c:\OLAttachments\" & strDomain
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Not fso.FolderExists(fol) Then
      fso.CreateFolder (fol)
    End If


' ================================================================
' ================================================================
' ================================================================



' ================================================================
'  save attachments
' ================================================================

  FileName = "C:\OLAttachments\" & strDomain & "\" & _
  Format(Item.CreationTime, "ddmmyyyy-") & Items.SenderEmailAddress & "-" & Atmt.FileName
  Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName


            i = i + 1

        strFile = Atmt.FileName

        strSQLquery1 = "INSERT INTO XSCRMEMAILSATTACHMENTS (" & vbCrLf & _
           "FileSavedIn," & vbCrLf & _
           "ActualFileName," & vbCrLf & _
           "UniqueIdentifier," & vbCrLf & _
           "SendersEmail" & vbCrLf & _
           ") VALUES ('" & FileName & "','" & StrUniqueID & "','" & strFile & "','" & strFromEmail & "')"


          Set rs = cnn.Execute(strSQLquery1)



          'If there is a GTDCommand, then grab the GTDId so we know which goal this resource belongs too.
             If InStr(strSubject, "gtdid=") > 0 Then
             strGoalId = Module5.GetHeaderProperty(strSubject, "gtdid=", ";", 5)
             End If




        AttachmentType = ""

        'If the attachment is png or jpg set attachment type string to image
        If (InStr(Atmt.FileName, ".png") > 0) Or (InStr(Atmt.FileName, ".jpg") > 0) Then
          AttachmentType = "image"
        End If

        'If attachment is .mov set attachment type string to video
        If InStr(Atmt.FileName, ".mov") > 0 Then
          AttachmentType = "video"
        End If

        'If the attachment is mp3 or m4a set attachment type string to audio
        If (InStr(Atmt.FileName, ".mp3") > 0) Or (InStr(Atmt.FileName, ".m4a") > 0) Then
          AttachmentType = "audio"
        End If



         'check to see if email sender is authorised
           If SenderAuthorised = "true" Then

          'If attachment type is an image, audio or video as per extensions above then populate the xscrmgtdresource table with following fields
         If (InStr(Atmt.FileName, ".png") > 0) Or (InStr(Atmt.FileName, ".jpg") > 0) Or (InStr(Atmt.FileName, ".mov") > 0) Or (InStr(Atmt.FileName, ".m4a") > 0) Or (InStr(Atmt.FileName, ".mp3") > 0) Then
              strSQLGTDResourceQuery = "INSERT INTO XSCRMGTDRESOURCES (" & vbCrLf & _
              "GoalId," & vbCrLf & _
              "Title," & vbCrLf & _
              "Type," & vbCrLf & _
              "insertdatetime," & vbCrLf & _
              "ResourcePath," & vbCrLf & _
              "UniqueIdentifier" & vbCrLf & _
            ") VALUES ('" & strGoalId & "','" & Atmt.FileName & "','" & AttachmentType & "',GETDATE(),'" & FileName & "','" & StrUniqueID & "')"


          End If

          Set rs = cnn.Execute(strSQLGTDResourceQuery)

          End If


   Next Atmt

' ================================================================
' ================================================================
' ================================================================


' ================================================================
'  Setting up to work with the Email Message Header
' ================================================================
  'This accesses the message header property and sets the variable MessageHeader
  Const PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"
  MessageHeader = objItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS)
  If MessageHeader <> "" Then

  End If
' ================================================================
' ================================================================
' ================================================================


' ================================================================
' Accessing the message header and collecting specific info for database tables
' ================================================================


 strSenderAccountDescription = Module5.GetHeaderProperty(MessageHeader, "From:", "<", 5)
 strContentType = Module5.GetHeaderProperty(MessageHeader, "Content-Type:", ";", 13)
 strMimeVersion = Module5.GetHeaderProperty(MessageHeader, "MIME-Version:", vbNewLine, 13)
 strReceived = Module5.GetHeaderProperty(MessageHeader, "Received:", "(", 9)

 'As the x-failed-recipients property does not appear in ALL messageheaders, we have to first check if it is present
 If InStr(MessageHeader, "X-Failed-Recipients:") > 0 Then
 'Get the MessageHeader Property value
 strFailedRcp = Module5.GetHeaderProperty(MessageHeader, "X-Failed-Recipients:", vbNewLine, 20)


 'Else set the variable value to blank so that we still have something to supply to the SQL query
 Else
 strFailedRcp = ""
 End If


' ================================================================
' ================================================================
' ================================================================


' ================================================================
' Save Email into the database DeplphiDude and table xsCRMEmails for attachment based emails and without attachments
' ================================================================


   If InStr(strSubject, "xs4crm") = 0 Then 'only insert if the emails is not a command

   strSQLquery = "INSERT INTO XSCRMEMAILS (" & vbCrLf & _
           "XFailedRecipients," & vbCrLf & _
           "Received," & vbCrLf & _
           "MimeVersion," & vbCrLf & _
           "ContentType," & vbCrLf & _
           "SendersAccountDescription," & vbCrLf & _
           "FromEmail," & vbCrLf & _
           "ToEmail," & vbCrLf & _
           "Subject," & vbCrLf & _
           "Body," & vbCrLf & _
           "SentDate," & vbCrLf & _
           "ReceivedDate," & vbCrLf & _
           "UniqueIdentifier," & vbCrLf & _
           "Status," & vbCrLf & _
           "AttachmentIcon," & vbCrLf & _
           "AssignedToUser," & vbCrLf & _
           "EmailHeader" & vbCrLf & _
           ") VALUES ('" & strFailedRcp & "','" & strReceived & "','" & strMimeVersion & "','" & strContentType & "','" & strSenderAccountDescription & "', '" & strFromEmail & "','" & strToEmail & "','" & strSubjectStripped & "','" & strBodyStripped & "','" & strSentDate & "','" & strReceivedDate & "','" & StrUniqueID & "','EmailStatus_New','" & AttachmentStr & "','','" & Module4.RemoveIllegalCharacters(MessageHeader) & "')"


          Set rs = cnn.Execute(strSQLquery)
   End If




' ================================================================
'  final steps
' ================================================================ 

'Delete email
objItem.Delete


Set objItem = Nothing
Set Atmt = Nothing


' ================================================================
'  close connection to the sql server and end the program
' ================================================================

cnn.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: perhaps some logging is in order?

Comment: What calls your code?  Is it an Outlook Event?  I'd log every time its fired and that will let you know where your issue might lie.

Comment: Its an Outlook "rule" that runs on incoming emails. Thanks for the tip, i shall look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add some logging to help track down the problem.

I haven't used this personally, but maybe give it a go: [Log4VBA](http://log4vba.everage.ca/)

Also, you should add error handling:

- [Error Handling and Debugging Tips for Access 2007, VB, and VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358847%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Error Handling In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used Log4VBA and inspected the logs, which showed me where the code was halting, and then from there it wasnt too difficult to figure out what was the cause of the problem. I had a poorly coded IF statement, and also some of the emails coming through had apostrophes in the TO: field, which meant the SQL query was failing, so i had to strip them out first.

All fixed now. Thanks again.

Comment: @Khuram Malik: happy to help.

Comment: WayBack machine is now needed to read about Log4VBA: http://web.archive.org/web/20081016125213/http://log4vba.everage.ca/

Answer (score 0):

First you do not say which part of your process is not working.  You have showed a routine that does not fire by itself, it must be called by something else.  This something else must have some conditions attached to it to call your routine.  What are they?  Can you show the workings of this.

If you are using a rule then could you show the conditions of the rule.  Further what about if instead of a rule we code for the event in the VBEditor so that you can maybe see this event happening as well?  Here is what I am talking about and there is example code there on how to do it [MSDN Application_New_MAIL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171307%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Next I agree with everyone else that you need some logging, there is so much going on and it is impossible to tell where you cod is falling over.  If I were you I would get an email that does not work and send it to yourself and have a break point right at the beginning of your code so that you can see a. That your code is actually being called and then where it is failing.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. The routine is fired by the send-receive button in Outlook. As soon as the send/receive process initiates, the VBA is called via an "Outlook Rule". I put some logging in place, which gave me some clues, and then i did some transactional logging on the SQL server and found that the data being passed to the fields was too large for the field sie limit. Thanks everyone for their help